# How can I lock object's height on pygtk3?

Tags: python, gtk

This is my code and I want to lock my button's and entry's height

https://gist.github.com/rayeshman/6473787

Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a demo in js fiddle so we can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `pack_start()` your widgets into the boxes, don't pass `True, True` for the "expand" and "fill" parameters unless you really want them to expand into and fill the available space. In this case, writing

```
self.vbox.pack_start(self.hbox2, False, False, 0)
```

will prevent the button and entry from growing larger in the vertical direction.

You might consider using `Gtk.Grid` for arranging your widgets - `Gtk.Box` doesn't necessarily listen to the `hexpand` and `vexpand` properties.